# JPA Check if entity can be deleted

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

How can I check if entity in JPA can be deleted and data integrity exception won't be thrown? Only way that came to my mind is to check all referenced entities one by one or try to delete in transaction and then rollback but is there some other simpler way?

Comment: do you want to know parent reference entity whether delete or not?

Answer (score 3):

If by "can be deleted" you mean "if entity exists in persistence context", you already answered your question:

> try to delete in transaction and then rollback

If something went wrong during transaction then rollback

Answer (score 1):

Well I use this approach...

```
public void doDelete() {        
    try {
        deleteData();           
    } catch (RuntimeException runtimeException) {
        if (getRootThrowable(runtimeException).getMessage().contains("Referential integrity constraint violation")) {
            //can't delete entity
        }               
    }
}

public static Throwable getRootThrowable(Throwable t) {
    Throwable result = t;

    while (result.getCause() != null) {
        result = result.getCause();
    }

    return result;
}
```

I'm not that fan of this, but it does the job for me...

Comment: I've had to use something similar in the past; often times ugly problems result in ugly solutions.

Comment: Yes I know it's ugly, but it's been in my apps since a long time.. and honestly it's doing the job, since sometimes I'm not only checking for   "violates foreign key constraint" also I want to know other errors... @MagicMan