# JPA Relation with same entity

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I use MYSQL, and I have employee table, contains

```
Employee {
     id, 
     name, 
     tel, 
     dayOfBirth, 
     manager_id
}
```

and the manager references to employee id, there is a database relation between the manager_id and id

I have create the entity class, and put relationship as following:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="manager_id", nullable=true,insertable=false,updatable=true)
private Employee manager;
```

I need to prevent deleting the manager if he has employees.

your help please.

Comment: May be this is what you are asking?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192536/jpa-check-if-entity-can-be-deleted

Answer (score 1):

Primary way is adding restriction in SQL schema.

```
PRIMARY KEY (ID) ,
FOREIGN KEY (MANAGER_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(ID) 
ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

In JPA you can check this using [@PreDestroy](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PreDestroy.html)

```
public class Employee {

@PreDestory
public void preDestroy()
   ( !getEmployees().isEmpty()) {
     // handle it
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i have try to add the the line ( ON DELETE NO ACTION ) then ( ON DELETE RESTRICTION ) but same :(, also i have tried to inset and delete direct from database and get same. maybe there is a parameter i have to pass to enable the restriction ???

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution, the solution to specify the engine as innodb as following:

ENGINE=INNODB

Thanks All